# Display a table below a bar chart in Power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a bar chart that shows a count of clients by monthly sales and I want to see the actual numbers. is it possible to put a table below that bar chart in Power BI, Any idea or link will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: This is what data labels are made for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Power BI's Visual table feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-see-data-see-records?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Alternatively, you can copy the bar chart visual, past it below the original bar chart, and change the new, duplicated bar chart to a table visualization.